# 1-D convolution neural network in Keras

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras

I am exploring 1-D CNN with Keras. My data is $\mathit{k}\times\mathit{N}$ where $\mathit{k}$ is the number of time stamps and $\mathit{N}$ is the number of features. I want to apply CNN with 1-D convolution so that the each filter processes. 
Can some explain what is meant by dilation in the context of conv1d in Keras (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first introduce a standard discrete convolution:
[image: A discrete convolution]

And a dilated convolution may look like this:
[image]
[image: A dilated convolution]

When l=1, the receptive field is 3*3; when l=2, the receptive field is going to be 5*5. We could get a larger receptive field at no cost. And this method is not gonna make the kernel bigger, which means we don't need to make more efforts to observe these larger receptive fields.

[image: The receptive field of the dilated convolution]

You may read the original article here: [Multi-Scale Context Aggregation by Dilated Convolutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07122)

And the following article will help you construct 1D convolutional neural networks:
[Introduction to 1D Convolutional Neural Networks in Keras for Time Sequences](https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf?gi=12ca7a6ae183)

The differences between convolutional neural networks:[A Comprehensive Introduction to Different Types of Convolutions in Deep Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-different-types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-669281e58215)

Comment: For dilation in 1-D convolution, will it sub-sample the features or the dilation will be applied on the time-axis only?